# Simplifying a Polynomial Expression with given information about parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have difficulty to solve the following question:

Let $w \neq 1$ complex number that satisfies $w^{3} = 1$,

Let $P(z) = 3 + 2z - 3z^{2} + 5z^{3} + 6z^{5} - 9z^{6}$

Calculate $P(1) + P(w) + P(w^{2})$

I have attempted the following calculations:

$P(1) = 4$

$P(w) = 3w^{2} + 2w - 1$

$P(w^{2}) = 2w^{2} + 3w - 1$

Hence, $P(1) + P(w) + P(w^{2}) = 5w^{2} + 5w + 2$

However, I believe there might be a parameter-less solution by utilizing the fact that $w^{3} = 1$. Could someone kindly guide me on how to proceed with this approach? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Alt. hint: $\;\; (w-1)\left(5w^{2} + 5w + 2\right) = 5 w^3 - 3 w - 2 = 3 - 3 w = -3\,(w - 1)\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$w^3-1 = (w-1)(w^2 + w + 1)$$

Comment: Thanks, I want to make sure I was able to understand correctly: I can conclude w^2 = -(w+1), and then 5w^2 + 5w + 2 = -5(w+1) + 5w + 2 = -3 ?

@Ingix

Comment: @MyLight Exactly. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

$P(1) + P(w) + P(w^{2})$ is a sum of terms of the form
$$
 a_k(1 + w^k + w^{2k})
$$
where $a_k$ are the coefficients of the polynomial $P$. If $k$ is a multiple of $3$ then $1 + w^k + w^{2k} = 3$. Otherwise $(1, w^k, w^{2k})$ is a permutation of $(1, w, w^2)$ and therefore $1 + w^k + w^{2k} = 0$.

So only the contributions of $P$ with exponents being a multiple of $3$ are needed, and
$$
P(1) + P(w) + P(w^{2}) = (3+5-9)\cdot 3 = -3 \, .
$$

---

This can be generalized: If $m$ is a prime number, $w \ne 1$ an $m$-th root of unity and $P(z) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_n z^n$ a polynomial then
$$
 P(1)+P(w) + \cdots + P(w^{m-1}) =
m (a_0 + a_m + a_{2m} + \cdots)
= m \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/m \rfloor} a_{km} \,.
$$

Comment: This is a similar argument as in Ingix's answer. I have posted it to demonstrate that the result can be obtained without computing $P(1), P(w), P(w^2)$ first.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The third root of unity: $w=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ has also the nice property: $w^2=\overline{w}$. It follows from your calculation
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{P(1)+P(w)+P(w^2)}&=5w^2+5w+2\\
&=5\overline{w}+5w+2\\
&=10\mathrm{Re}(w)+2\\
&=-5+2\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=-3}
\end{align*}